# lookup in Table with values similar to each other

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got a table that looks something like this:

```
Header1    Header2    Header3
Foobar1    someval    [Formula]
Smthelse   someother  [Formula]
Foobar2    //         [Formula]
Smthelse2  //         [Formula]
```

Everything in header 2 is manually entered.

I am trying to come up with a formula in header 3, that checks if the value from Header1 exists outside of the current row, even if there is a slight difference (for instance foobar1 and foobar2).
then it should add the value from header2 as a result.

I was trying to work with lookups, tried something arround the line of

`=VLOOKUP("*"&[@Header1]&"*";Table1;2;WRONG)"`

with no success. I tried,

`=IF(COUNTIF([Header1];"*"&[@Header1]&"*")>1;"exists";"doesnt exist")"`

which gave me the correct true or false values, but here I am failing to extract the value from Header2.

Here is what the expected output would look like:

```
Header1    Header2    Header3
Foobar1    someval    someval
Smthelse   someother  someother
Foobar2    //         someval
Smthelse2  //         someother
```

EDIT:

I'm going to be more specific here. My Table consists of URLS, and a column which is edited manually. Reason beeing, people want to sample out a bunch of websites (5000 sites) and manually check if they are brand safe.

Table looks like this:

```
+---------------------+------+
|        Site         | Safe |
+---------------------+------+
| yahoo.com           | Yes  |
| mobafire.com        | Yes  |
| m.yahoo.com         | Yes  |
| us.yahoo.com        | Yes  |
| www.gofeminin.de    | Yes  |
| beauty.gofeminin.de | Yes  |
| unsafe.site.com     | No   |
| m.unsafe.site.com   | No   |
+---------------------+------+
```

The "Safe" column is entered manually, by visiting the site, check if anything looks suspicios and then enter yes or no depending on wether it is safe or not.

to safe time, i want to add a new column, which checks if the site has a similar site, yahoo.com and us.yahoo.com for instance, which was already checked.

Comment: Better Edit the post & attach some sample data as Screen Shot for better understanding. I'm unable to understand   this ,,**if the value from Header1 exists outside of the current row, even if there is a slight difference (for instance foobar1 and foobar2).** !!

Comment: Is "similar" always a predictable difference that could be found with wildcards, like `foobar*`?  How similar is similar (what is the criterion for similar enough)?  You might want to check out fuzzy lookups: https://www.excel-university.com/perform-approximate-match-and-fuzzy-lookup-in-excel/.

Comment: added an edit, with more details to my question

Comment: What you look for is called fuzzy match, and there is not function for that in Excel.